# Order of addends in a sum affects the result?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following code, `op1` and `op2` should be identical. The only difference is in the order the addends appear in the sum. However, `np.array_equal(res1, res2)` returns `False`. Why does this happen? (I'm using TensorFlow version 0.12.1).

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

V = tf.constant([[-3.47429895, -5.99409866],
                 [-4.84888363, 5.3685813],
                 [8.32318401, 0.62552071]], dtype=tf.float32)

rs = tf.reduce_sum(V, axis=1, keep_dims=True)
m = -tf.matmul(V, V, transpose_b=True)
op1 = m + rs + tf.transpose(rs)
op2 = rs + tf.transpose(rs) + m

with tf.Session() as session:
    res1 = session.run(op1)
    res2 = session.run(op2)
    assert np.array_equal(res1, res2) # False, why?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because floating point operations are not accurate and changing the order can change the results albeit, the discrepancy is not significant.

The problem here is with `np.array_equal`, the error between `res1` and `res2` is more than it can tolerate. Try printing `res1 - res2` to get a better idea. You might want to use [numpy.allclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose) with properly chosen tolerance values.